# iOS Swift 3: Unrecognized selected sent to instance when trying to Segue from custom tableView header button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to segue after clicking a UIButton inside of a custom tableViewHeader cell. My code:

The Custom Header:

```
class MealsMealPlanHeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

  @IBOutlet weak var mealLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var mealCalories: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var editMeal: UIButton!
}
```

The relevant ViewController code:

```
class MealsMealPlanViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  let sections = ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Snacks"]
  let foods = ["Oatmeal", "Sandwich", "Yogurt"]
  let portions = ["160 calories, 1 cup", "200 calories, 1 serving", "80 calories, 1 cup"]

  let headerId = "mealPlanHeader"
  let cellId = "mealPlanCell"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MealsMealPlanTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MealsMealPlanHeaderTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerId)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerId) as! MealsMealPlanHeaderTableViewCell

    headerCell.mealLabel?.text = self.sections[section]
    headerCell.mealCalories?.text = "400"
    headerCell.editMeal.tag = section
    headerCell.editMeal.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPress(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return headerCell.contentView
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MealsMealPlanTableViewCell

    cell.foodLabel?.text = self.foods[indexPath.row]
    cell.foodCaloriePortion?.text = self.portions[indexPath.row]

    return cell
  }

  @IBAction func didPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("hello")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mealDetail", sender: sender)
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mealDetail" {
      print("made segue")
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foods.count
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
  }
```

I have a segue defined going from the ViewController in question to the ViewController destination in the storyboard with the correct identifier. I know the segue is causing the crash because when performSegue is removed, calling the IBAction alone works fine. Any ideas or alternate solutions?

EDIT: My error displays as follows:

```
2016-10-27 16:15:11.105 Army H.E.A.L.T.H.[9344:478088] ***         Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Army_H_E_A_L_T_H_.MealsMealDetailViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc94f535bf0'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the details of the exception.  Your explanation doesn't make sense since the segue will fire regardless of whether `prepare(for:)` is implemented or not.  Did you perhaps mean it works when `performSegue(withIdentifier:)` is removed?

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped, when I comment out performSegue there is no crash, not prepare. Edited post to make that more clear.

Comment: The exception says that your `MealsMealDetailViewController` doesn't implement the function `numberOfRowsInSection` - double check this class

Comment: I added the complete class to make things clearer. I have implemented number of rows in section. I think it has something to do with the fact that my custom cell is in an xib separate from the storyboard where the segue is defined?

Comment: No, the problem is in the destination view controller - `MealsMealDetailViewController`, not the `plan` view controller

Comment: Ah yes I hadn't considered the destination yet because I was so focused on the initial class. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your exception tells you the problem: 
**'-[Army_H_E_A_L_T_H_.MealsMealDetailViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** 
You must have set MealsMealDetailViewController as some UITableView's datasource but you aren't actually implementing the UITableViewDataSource protocol.  Your app crashes because it instantiates the tableView, the tableView asks your ViewController for the number of rows and the Objective C runtime throws an exception because it can't find that method on your ViewControllerer or any of its super classes.